# Does a B Tree work well for auto suggest/auto complete web forms?

Tags: search, grails, autocomplete, autosuggest, b-tree

Auto suggest/complete fields are used all over the web. Google has appeared to master it given that as soon as one types in a search query, suggestions are returned almost instantaneously.

I'm assuming the framework for achieving this involves a fast, in-memory data store on the web tier. We're building a Grails app based around retail products, so a user may search for `Can` which should suggest things like `Canon`, `Cancun`, etc, and wondering if a Java B-tree cached in memory would suffice for quick auto completes returned as JSON over AJAX. Outside of the jQuery AutoComplete field, do any frameworks and/or libraries exist to facilitate the development of this solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autocomplete is a text matching, information retrieval problem. Implementing your own B-tree and writing your own logic to match words to other words is something you could do. But then you would have to implement [Porter Stemming](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/), a [Vector Space Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model), and a [String-edit distance calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

...or you could use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) and its derivatives, which do a lot of this stuff already. If you really care about the data structures used to store this stuff, you could dive into its source. But I highly doubt writing your own and doing it all yourself would be more maintainable and efficient in the long run.

One of the more popular Grails ecosystem plugins for this is [Searchable](http://grails.org/plugin/searchable), which was mentioned in Ledbrook & Smith's [Grails in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988932). It uses Lucene under the covers, and make sit pretty easy to add full-text search to your domain classes. (For example, check out chapter 8 in GinA or the searchable docs).

Comment: This is great info...you just saved me a lot of necessary work, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Grails Richui plugin has an autocomplete that I've used in the past.  We had it hooked up to hit the database every keystroke (which I would not suggest but our data changed often enough that real-time data was required).  If your list of things is pretty static though then it could probably work well for you.

http://grails.org/plugin/richui#AutoComplete

Comment: RichUI is just for the user interface, I'm assuming the back end source is still left to the implementor, correct?

Comment: That is correct, the link gives a pretty good example.  In the gsp you tell it what controller/action to invoke when a key is pressed and then you implement that controller/action to return xml.