# Autcomplete words that were previously on a list

Tags: python, list, input, autocomplete, tabs

Autocomplete words which were previously on a list. That list was obtained by user input.

1. User inputs words which identifies them.

Ex: happy, lazy, skinny.

2. Then I want to store that into a list which will become a database.
3. I will do the same input as before, updated version, which will use the list created before and will autocomplete any tag that the user starts writing

Ex: If user enters L, all the words with L will appear. ex: Lazy, Likeable, Loser.

4. User scrolls down with the keyboard arrows and when he finds the correct word he presses tab to choose it.

In fact stackoverflow's Tags uses a version of what I want

Answer (score 1):

Starting from "I'm just building a toy for fun" and going to "I need the answer now and it's going into production", here are some suggestions:

1. The simplest code would be to simply find all strings that start with the current text.

   ```
   dictionary = ['happy', 'lazy', 'skinny']
   input_so_far = 'L'
   suggestions = [
       word
       for word in dictionary
       if word.lower().startswith(input_so_far.lower())
   ]
   ```
2. If you want simpl'ish code, but need a semi-serious solution that can cope with a serious dictionary, you'll need to look into some proper data structures, like B-trees, or...
3. ... if you have the text in a database (e.g. PostGreSQL), there may be builtin indices or plugins that would support textual search. But if you need the most general and/or performant solution...
4. ... [use a dedicated textual search capability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760430/does-a-b-tree-work-well-for-auto-suggest-auto-complete-web-forms) such as [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/index.html). Funny enough, textual auto-complete is something people do a lot of, so tools for handling text and doing rapid lookup are common and *really* good.

EDIT: as follow up, since it looks like you're looking for a way to do this in a simple terminal, check out [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187621/how-to-make-a-python-command-line-program-autocomplete-arbitrary-things-not-int) for suggestions about how to enable responsiveness with the user's input. Not all those solutions have auto-completion built in (some might), the point is more about how to get the input and what to do with the output of the approaches I suggest above.

Comment: I am new to python, didnt understand quite well. Where do I enter input and how to autocomplete?

Comment: My variable ``input_so_far`` is a substitute for some user input. You can use Python's built-in function ``input()`` to get text from console, but that won't return until the user hits <enter> so there's no opportunity for autocompletion. How you get user input, and what you do with the suggestions to display them, is going to be VERY dependent on where your code is running (console? curses? tkinter GUI? web? etc.), I can't give you a one-size-fits-all answer, and there's probably no clean way to do it in a typical console.

Comment: Ok I understood